# code reloading from 'lib' in rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm developing new component and don't want to waste time on reloading environment each time.

I've found few related questions, but no one solution worked for me.
So what is the technique to automatically reload code from lib folder when sources changed?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following line in the config/application.rb.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```